# jQuery: copy contents, strip <p> tags, and create linebreaks

Tags: jquery, tags, textarea, markup, strip

I've succesfully created a behavior that copies the contents of a div container into a textarea field:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var contents = $('.content').html();
    $('textarea').val(contents);    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/foomarks/E5sPj/6/

However, I'm stumped on:

1. How to strip the paragraph tags.
2. How to create a single line break to denote where the paragraph tag would be stripped.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/E5sPj/12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('a').click(function() {

var contents = $('.content').html();
contents = contents.replace(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/gi,"$1\n");
$('textarea').val(contents);    

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function() {

    var contents = $('.content').html();

    contents = contents.replace(/<p>/g, '');
    contents = contents.replace(/<\/?p>/g, '\r\n');

    $('textarea').val(contents);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/E5sPj/9/

If you want to replace the leading spaces too, do this:

```
$('a').click(function() {

    var contents = $('.content').html();

    contents = contents.replace(/\s{2,}/g, '');
    contents = contents.replace(/<p>/g, '');
    contents = contents.replace(/<\/?p>/g, '\r\n\r\n');

    $('textarea').val(contents);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/E5sPj/11/

Comment: I prefer my answer because it is in one Regex expression. Also, I added the case insensitive flag just in case we have something like <P>.